# Genymotion in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, sdk, bundle, genymotion

I'm using Eclipse Bundle SDK to make android apps, but the actual ADV from Eclipse is so slow, and I found Genymotion.

I follow all guides and I have the same problem.

I have all configurated, VirtualBox, Genymotion with some devices and "run configuration" from Eclipse program. But when I run the application and I try to pick Genymotion, this doesn't appear. I don't know what I need to do.
This is an example http://gyazo.com/9d233050af68116d1e2208bab2ed516e

I started device from plugin before try to run program.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You probably need to configure the Android SDK path in the Genymotion settings, in the ADB panel. 
Beware, it is not the path to ADB, but the path to the SDK that must be set.

If correctly set, you will see the message "ADB and AAPT from android developper tools successfully found."

[image: ADB Panel of Genymotion settings]